# How to convert JSON date to string in Kotlin within my recyclerview adapter?

Tags: android, kotlin

The [JSON data](https://api.nasa.gov/mars-photos/api/v1/rovers/curiosity/photos?sol=1000&camera=fhaz&api_key=DEMO_KEY) I am returning is a string in numbered format (YYYY-MM-DD) and I am wanting my app to display this as ex.(January 1, 2020) depending on which JSON date I query.

Given the date formatting options in java and kotlin are based off integers, I am unsure of the most efficient way to convert the numbered string to a character string when queried.  I do not want a function with 50 lines converting the strings.  Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Please try using SimpleDateFormat. With SimpleDateFormat you can convert dates to different formats with just 3 lines of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First convert YYYY-MM-DD date string to Date

```
val date = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US).parse("2015-05-30")
```

Then convert the date to your preferred format

```
 val formattedDatesString = SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy", Locale.US).format(date)
```

But instead of doing this in your adapter, you should use dedicated object to hold the data so that in onBindViewHolder would not need to calculate anything

Comment: After a few searches online I found this the easiest way to do it. But, I found a significant issue in my case. I am fetching data from Google Spreadsheet and the dates in the spreadsheet are shown as 01-Jan-23. When I show this in the `recyclerView` it shows 31-Dec-2022 for 01-Jan-23, 01-Jan-23 for 02-Jan-23 and so on (one day earlier). I do not have time in the spreadsheet, by the way. How can I fix it?

Comment: Can paste some code snippet? Can you ensure that format is correct? @Codist

Comment: As I can see that the issue is not with the Kotlin code, please find my post here. https://stackoverflow.com/q/75273959/13935956